# Amazon Alexa Intent not recognizing slot

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a simple Alexa app. Language is en-AU.

I am testing in the console. I am typing, not using a microphone, so the problem is not in speech recognition.

On launch, I ask the user for the bus stop number. The intent definition JSON is below.

If I type "it is 3038" it works. Alexa calls my custom intent and the number is recognized and passed to lambda function. All good.

But if I type "it's 3038" it doesn't work! A built-in fallback intent is triggered instead.

Also, if I just put a number, it doesn't work. A lot of other phrases don't work either even though I am typing exactly the same phrase from the intent slot definition.

Why is this not working reliably and how can I let users provide just a number without using a specific phrase that Alexa likes.

```
{
                "name": "GetBusStopIntent",
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "stop",
                        "type": "AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER"
                    }
                ],
                "samples": [
                    "Stop number is {stop}",
                    "It is {stop}",
                    "Bus stop number is {stop}",
                    "It's {stop}",
                    "{stop}"
                ]
            }
```

Comment: to correctly identify it in the test portal stop 3038 would be rendered as ‘my stop is three zero three eight’ also play with just utilizing  AMAZON.NUMBER instead of FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER my experience is you’ll get better reckoning of the utterance

Comment: @ChuckLaPress thanks for that, it would never occur to me to type number words! Why don't you put that in the answer?

Comment: Can you check what locale simulator is using in alexa console. It happens sometime when you are targeting multiple locale in alexa skill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify spoken numbers in the Amazon provided testing suite as in your specific use case.
 stop 3038 would be rendered as ‘my stop is three zero three eight’ also play with just utilizing AMAZON.NUMBER instead of FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER my experience is you’ll get better reckoning of the utterance

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and the fix was very simple.

As you are using the keyboard to enter text for the SLOT for 4 digit number, you want to enter in WORDS, and not as digits

you are trying "it is 3038" instead you should type "it is three zero three eight"